# SQL Query behaving weird

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Below queries in sql giving weird results. Please help me to understand why it is happening.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SP_MNP_DownLoadFiles @FileTypeId,@UserId',N'@FileTypeId smallint,@UserId bigint',@FileTypeId=2,@UserId=18 -- This query returns nothing

Exec SP_MNP_DownLoadFiles @FileTypeId=2,@UserId=18 -- This query returns some result

Select Type as FileTypeId ,FileStream as Attachment FROM MNPFiles
        where CustomerId = 18
        AND
        Type = 2 -- This is the query inside SP.
```

Please consider the data types are same everywhere.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: "Behaving weird". Yep, voting to close.

Comment: Are you asking why executing a proc using `sp_executesql` doesn't return anything, but running a straight `Exec` does?

Comment: You are right, I ran it and it did nothing :(

Comment: try including "EXEC" in the dynamic string in your first query:   N' EXEC SP_MNP_..."

Comment: @blindy why ? What is my fault ? I am just a beginner. At least you could have guided me.

Comment: I ran sql profiler and found exec sp_executesql N'SP_MNP_DownLoadFiles @FileTypeId,@UserId',N'@FileTypeId smallint,@UserId bigint',@FileTypeId=2,@UserId=18 in profiler and  returning nothing. In-fact the sp is getting called from my application. I am not that good in SQl forgot to mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dynamic SQL string doesn't match your non-dynamic statement.

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC SP_MNP_DownLoadFiles ...',...
                     ^^^^
```

Other things to check:

1. Other `SELECT`s in your stored procedure prior to your main one. You may need to `SET NOCOUNT ON`.
2. That you're not `RETURN`ing something before your main query

Comment: Thanks @Cory I am going to check these things.